# Tick intervals are logarithm for both y axes in Dual Y axis plot if one plot is linear and the other is logarithm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting two numpy arrays, called line1 and line2 respectively, against a fixed x axis. One array is to be plotted in a log plot using *semilogy* and the other array is plotted in a basic linear plot on the same x axis.

The scaling format for both the y axes seem to be fine. However the y axis tick intervals and scale for the right linear plot (line2) appears to be logarithm (with the closely spaced ticks) and I can't seem to find a way to change it.

Is there a way to change the right y axis in the plot below to linear?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
y = np.exp(x)
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

fig1 = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
line1 = ax1.semilogy(x,y)
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(111, sharex=ax1, frameon=False)
line2 = ax2.plot(x,y2,"r")    

#MATPLOTLIB BUG? THE SECOND Y AXES HAS A LOG SCALE AND THE TICK LABELS CAN'T BE CHANGED
ax2.set_yscale('linear') 
ax2.yaxis.tick_right() 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ax2 = ax1.twinx()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx) instead of `add_subplot` again. That will separate the y-ticks on the new axes from the ones on the old axis. From the docs:

> `twinx()`
>
> create a twin of Axes for generating a plot with a sharex x-axis but independent y axis. The y-axis of self will have ticks on left and the returned axes will have ticks on the right.

You also then don't need to set the `yscale` to `linear`, or move the ticks to the right, as that is done automatically by `twinx`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
y = np.exp(x)
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

fig1 = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
line1 = ax1.semilogy(x,y)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()      # <-- Note the change to twinx here
line2 = ax2.plot(x,y2,"r")    

plt.show()
```

[image]